# Sorting Arrays in Java and handle any null values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Need to write a sort method for my project.. Its a cardgame. These are the specs for the method.

- cannot use arrays.sort() or any other external library routines.
- sort the Hand in ascending order of Card VALUE
- set sorted to true.
- handle cases when arrays(hand) are not full / contain nulls.  and
  handle the cases when the cards array is not full.

Below is the code I have so far, working but need to handle nulls and not full arrays(hand). Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public void sortHand(){
    // loop over every slot
    for (int i = 0 ; i < cards.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < cards.length; j++) {
            //getValue returns face value of card
            if(cards[j].getValue().compareTo(cards[i].getValue()) < 0) {
                //swap
                Card temp = cards[i];
                cards[i] = cards[j];
                cards[j] = temp;
            }
            else {
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    isSorted = true;
}
```

Comment: what's the use of that `isSorted` variable? 

Comment: @Mritunjay Its the sorted status of the hand.. used in other methods too..

Comment: @NicoleYork it is a poor practice to have such a variable.

Comment: Well, which side of the array should null values be on after sorted?

Comment: The question is not clearly, please clarify it, if you just want to handle null then just use a `if(cards == null)` before loop.

Comment: Hint: `if (cards[j] == null || cards[i] == null) { do something }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad it was given to me by my teacher, it has to be used..

Comment: That's fine, but you should know. That is why I mention it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's not necessarily poor practice. If a hand can be either unsorted or sorted, it makes sense to keep track of its state. It's quicker than performing an O(n) scan if you're going to be checking it frequently.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that is premature optimization and a serious opportunity for bugs due to out of sync state. It moves information about the array outside of the array into an arbitrary, dissociated flag. If you need an array to be sorted, sort it. If you have identified a bottleneck, optimizing may be appropriate in which case this is still a less than stellar approach. In fact, in your answer, which is good, you identify such a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't assume any particular number of cards, so it already handles non-full hands. Nothing needed there.

> ```
> if(cards[j].getValue().compareTo(cards[i].getValue()) < 0)
> ```

You need to handle the cases where `cards[i]` or `cards[j]` is null. You don't want to call `.getValue()` on a null value; it'll throw a `NullPointerException`.

There are three cases to handle: one card is null, the other one is null, or both are. If they're both null you don't need to swap anything. If one is null but not the other, you need to decide if null goes first or last. In one case you'll swap and in the other you'll do nothing.

```
if (cards[i] == null && cards[j] == null) {
    // no swap
}
else if (cards[i] == null && cards[j] != null) {
    // swap if nulls go last, otherwise do nothing
}
else if (cards[i] != null && cards[j] == null) {
    // swap if nulls go first, otherwise do nothing
}
else if (cards[j].getValue().compareTo(cards[i].getValue()) < 0) {
    ...
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to combine the appropriate "swap" cases into a single `if` using `||`. Be careful! You need to do make sure neither card is null before you call `.getValue()`. The order of the checks is crucial.

> ```
> else {
>     isSorted = false;
> }
> ```

There's no need for this clause, by the way. Just set `isSorted` to `true` at the end of the method. You don't need to set it to `false` in the middle of sorting. Nobody's going to check the flag while you're actively sorting the hand.